# Android how to animate transition from details fragment to listview fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Need to animate transition from details fragment to listview fragment, like transition of viewpager. But it need to be vertical orientation and transtion will navigate to list fragment. Here is example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=650vFss54O4 , Thanks

Comment: Do you know that your video is private? Nobody sees it.

Comment: The video is not accessible to public users.

Comment: Change access, thanks